# How to handle callbacks in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback, python-requests

I have a custom HTTP method/verb (lets say `LISTEN`) which allows me to listen for an update on a resource stored on a remote server. The API available for this has a blocking call which will get my client code to listen for an update till I interrupt the execution of that call. Just to provide an example, if I were to perform a curl as follows:

```
curl -X LISTEN http://<IP-Address>:<Port>/resource
```

The execution of this creates a blocking call, providing me updates on the resource whenever a new value for this resource is pushed to the server (similar to a pub-sub model), the response for that would look similar to this:

```
{"data":"value update 1","id":"id resource"}
{"data":"value update 2","id":"id resource"}
(...)
```

If I were to write code to handle this in Python, how do I call my url using this custom verb and handle the blocking call/call back while ensuring that this does not block the execution of the rest of my code?

Comment: I guess you can handle this situation you describe by using multithreading and semaphores.

Comment: @Manuel - any examples that I can refer to for this?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python `requests` lib [with a custom HTTP verb](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#custom-verbs) and [need to read stream content](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-requests), you can do something like this:

```py
import json
import requests  # sudo pip3 install requests


url = "http://........."
r = requests.request('LISTEN', url, stream=True)
for line in r.iter_lines():
    # filter out keep-alive new lines
    if line:
        decoded_line = line.decode('utf-8')
        print(json.loads(decoded_line))
```

Note: by default all `requests` calls are blocking, so you need to run this code in a separate thread/process to avoid that.

> ...while ensuring that this does not block the execution of the rest of my code

Since you provided no details about your application, I will try to list some general thoughts on question.

Your task can be solved in **many ways**. Solution depends on your app architecture.

If this is a web server, you can take a look at [tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#request-objects)(see *streaming callback*) or [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/streams.html) streaming examples.

On the other hand you can run the code above in a separate process and communicate with other applications/services using RabbitMQ for example (or other [ipc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) mechanism).

Comment: I tried running your snippet but I'm getting the same issue of it being in a blocking state. To expand upon my question, I'm trying to call the `LISTEN` function of an Opensource DHT implementation called [OpenDHT](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/opendht/wiki/REST-API).

Comment: In this, I'm hitting its REST endpoints for interacting with this application and get values associated with a resource (key) stored on this DHT network. I have tried looking at the `Requests` library but have not been able to successfully call the custom verb `LISTEN`, while being able to execute some other logic, for instance - read data from a file and run some computation on it and then place it on the DHT network and trigger a `LISTEN` call on that resource/key inserted into the DHT. The reading process and `LISTEN` should be done simultaneously

Comment: Yes, sorry, I failed to mention that any `requests` call is a blocking one, so if you want ot use this snippet in non-blocking way, you should put it into a separate process or thread (I'd go for a process, see the last sentece of the answer).

Comment: thanks for pointing out that concept. I did think about it and ended up looking at `asyncio` in Python initially but I still faced the same issue. This endpoint forms a connection, and sends values one at a time (as JSON), but when I make the `LISTEN` call, it always stays in that state without progressing further, so I can't access any of the values (if at all being returned). I'm honestly unsure of how to tackle this.